# Google Maps Utility installation

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to use the new Google Maps Utility for Android (I need to create clusters in my map). I'm following every steps of the tutorial to install the library, but one java file is having some problems : DefaultClusterRenderer.

Here's the problems :
I can't import :

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.TimeInterpolator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
```

This 'HONEYCOMB' cannot be resolved :

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
```

TimeInterpolator :

```
TimeInterpolator cannot be resolved to a type
```

AnimeListenerAdapter :

```
AnimatorListenerAdapter cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: I am also coming across the exact errors you have encountered, very interested in how to resolve...

Comment: well, what i did is rebuild the library with le last SDK (Android 4.3) instead of Android 2.2, i should put this an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I build to Android 4.3 and it worked like a charm.